# How does the regular expression `new RegExp("user=" + un + "[\"'\\s>]", "i")` work?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a Javascript Junkie and wishing to test around some codes.

```
new RegExp("user=" + un + "[\"'\\s>]", "i")
```

what will this actually mean?

It was from a site, and it actually works!

I especially don't get the `[\"'\\s>]` part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[` and `]` signify a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Basically, it will match one of any characters found within. The backslash `\` [escapes special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). So you'll see that the first double-quote is escaped, showing we're looking for the `"` char within the value, and not merely using the `"` within our regular expression to wrap around a value. Then the single-quote `'` is considered, followed by a backslash (literal - so it too must be escaped `\\` looks for one backslash). It appears the original was indicating a space, which is `\s`. And then the greater-than symbol.

Comment: @webzide You are welcome. Welcom to the greatest programming site eva!

Answer (score 4):

`[\"'\s>]` means any of the following characters: " ' space >

So, assuming `un = "abc"` your regex would match any of the following:

```
user=abc"
user=abc'
user=abc  // There is a space after abc.
user=abc>
```

Comment: Good example!  And for completeness, since the "i" flag was passed in to the constructor, USER=aBc>, uSeR=ABc' etc would all also match.

Answer (score 1):

```
[\"'\\s>]
```

represents a char class containing 4 thing: a double quote, a single quote, a `\s`, and a `>`. It matches either one of these four once. The `\s` in turn could mean a single white space which could come from a space, tab, newline, carriage return.

The extra `\` you see are for escaping.